# I am trying to format my label text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label, format-string

I want my `Label` use the `{0:c2}` format; however, it doesn't seem to work when I do it the following way:

Client code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label" StringFormat="{}{0:c2}"></asp:Label>
```

Server code (on page load):

```
Dim dvSql7 As DataView = DirectCast(SqlDataSource7.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
    For Each drvSql7 As DataRowView In dvSql7
        Label4.Text = drvSql7("goal").ToString()

    Next
```

What the problem might be? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What are you expecting to get vs. what is it giving you?

Comment: i get the number 12345.543533 and i want $12345.54

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `StringFormat` property of the Label control.  What you need to do is format the string before it gets assigned to the `Label.Text` property:

`Label4.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(drvSql7("goal")).ToString("c")`

Comment: OK I updated the answer, try again.  Sorry I had a major brain fart on my initial answer.